# Is it possible to create a topic subscription in an azure function app?

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I do know we can create a subscription in ASB, but I wanted to know if the subscription does not exist, can we create one in the azure function app itself? To give more context, if there is a topic trigger in my function app, I want to check if the subscription exists or not. If it does, it uses it, but if not needs to create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

That'd be a chicken and egg situation. The entity has to be there for a function to be triggered by an entity (queue or subscription on a topic). Otherwise, there's no message to receive that would trigger the function in the first place.

You can work around it by running during Function's initial start-up, but that's not something that is supported by the Functions service natively. In my [post](https://weblogs.asp.net/sfeldman/automatic-queue-creation-for-function) I show how to achieve that using `FunctionsStartup` (In-Proc SDK). A similar approach could be used with the Isolated Worker SDK.

You can also express your interest in the feature to be provided by Functions if you'd like by [letting the team know](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-servicebus-extension/issues/130).